Bluetooth will not work - Bluez not running
I run Ubuntu 22.04. I ran 'journalctl -xeu bluetooth.service and got the below error message.
How do I fix this. I have updated Bluez but that doesn't help.
Thanks RP
Jul 22 10:39:31 rick-MS-7C02 systemd[1]: Stopped Bluetooth service.
Subject: A stop job for unit bluetooth.service has finished >Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
A stop job for unit bluetooth.service has finished.
The job identifier is 7250 and the job result is done.
Jul 22 10:39:31 rick-MS-7C02 systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jul 22 10:39:31 rick-MS-7C02 systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Subject: Unit failed
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
The unit bluetooth.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 22 10:39:31 rick-MS-7C02 systemd[1]: Failed to start Bluetooth service.
Subject: A start job for unit bluetooth.service has failed
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
A start job for unit bluetooth.service has finished with a failure.

